# como hago para que en el VSC al poner <img src="" me ponga un menu o me permita buscar dentro de las carpeta una imagen

Tags: html, css, web

<img src="______" no me aparece un menu o algo donde buscat la imagena insertar. la opcion es buscar la ruta imagen por imagen pero es algo bastante poco practico. Estoy usando VSC y no quiero volver al Dreamwever

Comment: lo estoy trabajando en html, el resto de las etiquetas se autocompleta sin problemas , salvo la infreme y img src

Comment: dudo que te autocomplete el source.. no es algo que se suela autocompletar, por lo menos en vsc

Comment: no busco que sea auto completado pero si me de la opcion de poner un "examinar" y de ahi buscar la ruta.